# How does NOT IN subquery work with NULL values?

Tags: mysql

I am confused how the following works in MySQL. In the queries below, the first `SELECT` returns all rows from `table2` while the second `SELECT` returns none of the rows. Is there an explanation of how `NULL` works with the `NOT IN` operator. Is there any documentation to explains this?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   table1_id INT UNSIGNED,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO table2 (id, table1_id) VALUES (1, NULL);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1);
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+

INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (1);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1);
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that according to the SQL specification, `Foo IN(A,B,C)` translates to `( Foo = A Or Foo = B Or Foo = C )`. Thus, if we have `Foo In(Null, 1, 2)` we get `Foo = Null Or Foo = 1 Or Foo = 2`. Since `Foo = Null` is always `UNKNOWN` and evaluated to `False` for purposes of filtering, Nulls in your IN expression will return no results.

Comment: You can make it work by adding `where id is not null` to the subsquery

Comment: @Bohemian - Of course. However, the OP is asking specifically why NULL in your IN clause returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `IFNULL(id, '')` to sub-query so it will work, example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id NOT IN (SELECT IFNULL(id, '') FROM table1);
```